# Cannot fix fsck errors after system crashing

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, windows-8, fsck

I have a dual partition with Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 16.04. While updating and restarting Windows I forced to turn off my laptop by pressing the power button. After that Ubuntu presents a lot of problems, I tried to fix them by using the `fsck` command but that was not possible and in addition I could not work since the file system adopted a `read-only` configuration.

I decided then to change the configuration of the file `/etc/fstab` for the relevant partition, that is `\dev\sda9`. I modified the keyword `remount=ro` to `continue`. After that I have been using the laptop for around 20 minutes without problems, however the errors are still present as the output of the following command reveals:

```
~$ fsck -n /dev/sda9

fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
e2fsck 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
Warning: skipping journal recovery because doing a read-only filesystem check.
/dev/sda9 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found. Fix? no
Inode 655158 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Deleted inode 655251 has zero dtime.  Fix? no
Inode 655385 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 655387 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 655665 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 922377 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 939006 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Block bitmap differences:  -(1746438--1746450)-(17541643--17541655)
Fix? no
Inode bitmap differences:  -655158 -655251 -655385 -655387 -655665 -922377 -939006
Fix? no

/dev/sda9: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********
/dev/sda9: 1665447/27275136 files (0.4% non-contiguous), 76152874/109312000 blocks
```

Will there be a way to fix it?

Comment: Let it do an fsck on the next boot by running `sudo touch /forcefsck`. Then restart.

Comment: The ouput of `fsck` persists

Comment: Then please try booting from an Ubuntu live USB or DVD and run the fsck from there, while your installation partition is unmounted, and without the `-n` option.